# Execution optimizations have been disabled for task ':compileGsonViews'

Tags: gradle, grails, json-view

We recently upgraded our project from Grails 3 to 5.1.1. Actually, it was not really an upgrade but rather a migration. We ended up creating a fresh project with 5.1.1 and migrated all of our code into it. Everything is currently working with an exception of one warning:

```
> Task :compileGsonViews
Execution optimizations have been disabled for task ':compileGsonViews' to ensure correctness due to the following reasons:
  - Gradle detected a problem with the following location: '/Users/shurikag/PRIZ/dev/priz-api/build/gson-classes/main'. Reason: Task ':bootWarMainClassName' uses this output of task ':compileGsonViews' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.3.3/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more details about this problem.
```

And in fact, as our newrelic shows, the app is now extremely slow on gson rendering. Usually the first time an endpoint is called, it is very slow, the subsequent calls are OK.

Is there a solution for it?

Here is our `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core"
        }
        maven {
            url "https://repo.grails.org/artifactory/core"
        }
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.grails:grails-gradle-plugin:$grailsGradlePluginVersion"
        classpath "org.grails.plugins:hibernate5:7.2.0"
        classpath "org.grails.plugins:views-gradle:2.1.2"
        classpath "gradle.plugin.com.github.erdi.webdriver-binaries:webdriver-binaries-gradle-plugin:2.6"
        classpath 'org.grails.plugins:database-migration:3.1.0'
    }
}

version "0.1"
group "priz.api"

apply plugin: "eclipse"
apply plugin: "idea"
// apply plugin:"visual-studio"
apply plugin: "war"
apply plugin: "org.grails.grails-web"
apply plugin: "org.grails.plugins.views-json"
apply plugin: "com.github.erdi.webdriver-binaries"

repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core"
    }
    maven {
        url "https://repo.grails.org/artifactory/core"
    }
    mavenCentral()
}

configurations {
    developmentOnly
    runtimeClasspath {
        extendsFrom developmentOnly
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation platform('com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-bom:1.11.1000')
    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-s3'
    developmentOnly("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools")
    compileOnly "io.micronaut:micronaut-inject-groovy"
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.micronaut/micronaut-core
    implementation 'io.micronaut:micronaut-core:3.2.6'

    console "org.grails:grails-console"
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:2.6.2"
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation:2.6.2"
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:2.6.2"
    implementation "org.grails:grails-core"
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:2.6.2"
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:2.6.2"
    implementation "org.grails:grails-plugin-url-mappings"
    implementation "org.grails:grails-plugin-rest"
    implementation "org.grails:grails-plugin-codecs"
    implementation "org.grails:grails-plugin-interceptors"
    implementation "org.grails:grails-plugin-services"
    implementation "org.grails:grails-plugin-datasource"
    implementation "org.grails:grails-plugin-databinding"
    implementation "org.grails:grails-web-boot"
    implementation "org.grails:grails-logging"
    implementation "org.grails.plugins:cache"
    implementation "org.grails.plugins:async"
    implementation "org.grails.plugins:events"
    implementation "org.grails.plugins:hibernate5"
    implementation "org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.6.3.Final"
    implementation 'org.hibernate:hibernate-ehcache:5.6.3.Final'
    implementation "org.grails.plugins:views-json:2.1.2"
    implementation "org.grails.plugins:views-json-templates:2.1.2"
    profile "org.grails.profiles:rest-api"
    runtimeOnly "org.glassfish.web:el-impl:2.2.1-b05"
    runtimeOnly "com.h2database:h2"
    runtimeOnly "org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc"
    runtimeOnly "javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.3.1"
    testImplementation "io.micronaut:micronaut-inject-groovy"
    testImplementation "org.grails:grails-gorm-testing-support"
    testImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-core"
    testImplementation "io.micronaut:micronaut-http-client"
    testImplementation "org.grails:grails-web-testing-support"
    testImplementation "org.grails:views-json-testing-support"
    testImplementation "org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:6.1.7.Final"
    testImplementation "org.grails.plugins:geb"
    testImplementation "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-remote-driver:4.0.0"
    testImplementation "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-api:4.0.0"
    testImplementation "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-support:4.0.0"
    testRuntimeOnly "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-chrome-driver:4.0.0"
    testRuntimeOnly "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-firefox-driver:4.0.0"
    runtimeOnly "org.grails.plugins:async:4.0.0"

    implementation 'org.grails.plugins:postgresql-extensions:7.0.0'
    implementation "org.postgresql:postgresql:42.3.1"
    implementation 'org.grails.plugins:database-migration:3.1.0'
    implementation 'org.liquibase:liquibase-core:3.10.3'

    implementation "org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:4.0.3"
    implementation "org.grails.plugins:spring-security-rest:3.0.1"
    implementation 'com.auth0:auth0:1.35.0'
    implementation 'com.auth0:jwks-rsa:0.20.0'

    implementation 'com.sendinblue:sib-api-v3-sdk:5.2.0'

    implementation 'com.papertrailapp:logback-syslog4j:1.0.0'
    implementation "com.stripe:stripe-java:17.11.0"
    implementation "org.grails:grails-datastore-gorm-async"
    implementation 'org.quartz-scheduler:quartz:2.3.2'

    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.9.3'

    implementation 'co.elastic.clients:elasticsearch-java:7.16.2'
    implementation 'jakarta.json:jakarta.json-api:2.0.1'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.12.3'
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        resources {
            srcDir 'grails-app/migrations'
        }
    }
}

bootRun {
    ignoreExitValue true
    jvmArgs(
            '-Dspring.output.ansi.enabled=always',
            '-noverify',
            '-XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1',
            '-Xmx1024m')
    sourceResources sourceSets.main
    String springProfilesActive = 'spring.profiles.active'
    systemProperty springProfilesActive, System.getProperty(springProfilesActive)
}

tasks.withType(GroovyCompile) {
    configure(groovyOptions) {
        forkOptions.jvmArgs = ['-Xmx1024m']
    }
}

tasks.withType(Test) {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

webdriverBinaries {
    chromedriver '2.45.0'
    geckodriver '0.30.0'
}

tasks.withType(Test) {
    systemProperty "geb.env", System.getProperty('geb.env')
    systemProperty "geb.build.reportsDir", reporting.file("geb/integrationTest")
    systemProperty "webdriver.chrome.driver", System.getProperty('webdriver.chrome.driver')
    systemProperty "webdriver.gecko.driver", System.getProperty('webdriver.gecko.driver')
}
```

**UPDATE**

Steps to reproduce on a freshly made project

```
~/PRIZ/dev $ grails -v
| Grails Version: 5.1.1
| JVM Version: 11.0.12
~/PRIZ/dev $ grails create-app myapp --profile=rest-api
| Application created at /Users/shurikag/PRIZ/dev/myapp
~/PRIZ/dev $ cd myapp
~/PRIZ/dev/myapp $ ./gradlew assemble
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)

> Task :compileGroovy
09:32:41.216 [/127.0.0.1:57662 to /127.0.0.1:57661 workers] DEBUG io.micronaut.core.optim.StaticOptimizations - No optimizations class io.micronaut.core.io.service.SoftServiceLoader$Optimizations found
09:32:41.826 [/127.0.0.1:57662 to /127.0.0.1:57661 workers] DEBUG io.micronaut.core.optim.StaticOptimizations - No optimizations class io.micronaut.core.reflect.ClassUtils$Optimizations found
09:32:42.282 [/127.0.0.1:57662 to /127.0.0.1:57661 workers] DEBUG io.micronaut.core.optim.StaticOptimizations - No optimizations class io.micronaut.core.util.EnvironmentProperties found

> Task :compileGsonViews
Execution optimizations have been disabled for task ':compileGsonViews' to ensure correctness due to the following reasons:
  - Gradle detected a problem with the following location: '/Users/shurikag/PRIZ/dev/myapp/build/gson-classes/main'. Reason: Task ':bootWarMainClassName' uses this output of task ':compileGsonViews' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.2/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more details about this problem.
09:32:44.382 [main] DEBUG io.micronaut.core.optim.StaticOptimizations - No optimizations class io.micronaut.core.reflect.ClassUtils$Optimizations found
09:32:44.388 [main] DEBUG io.micronaut.core.optim.StaticOptimizations - No optimizations class io.micronaut.core.util.EnvironmentProperties found
09:32:45.040 [pool-1-thread-2] DEBUG io.micronaut.core.optim.StaticOptimizations - No optimizations class io.micronaut.core.io.service.SoftServiceLoader$Optimizations found

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

Execution optimizations have been disabled for 1 invalid unit(s) of work during this build to ensure correctness.
Please consult deprecation warnings for more details.
```

**UPDATE**

If I update `grailsGradlePluginVersion` to `5.1.1` and run the app with `grails run-app`, I am facing another issue:

```
| Running application...
<=============> 100% EXECUTING [16s]
> IDLE
Failed to instantiate [ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext]
Reported exception:
ch.qos.logback.core.LogbackException: Unexpected filename extension of file [file:/Users/shurikag/PRIZ/dev/priz-api/grails-app/conf/logback.groovy]. Should be either .groovy or .xml
        at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer.configureByResource(ContextInitializer.java:67)
        at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer.autoConfig(ContextInitializer.java:140)
        at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.init(StaticLoggerBinder.java:84)
        at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.<clinit>(StaticLoggerBinder.java:55)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:150)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:124)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:417)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:362)
        at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:155)
        at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:290)
```

Comment: What value does `grailsGradlePluginVersion` have?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown It's 5.1.0 
Tried upgrading to 5.1.1, and some other things completely exploded.

Comment: If you change `grailsGradlePluginVersion` in `gradle.properties` to 5.1.1 does it work?

Comment: "Tried upgrading to 5.1.1, and some other things completely exploded." - I can't reproduce that.

Comment: I will try again. and will report back :)

Comment: @JeffScottBrown See the last update in the post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to get the error to go away. All I needed to do it all the dependency config for the related tasks (in build.gradle):

```
tasks.named('bootWarMainClassName') {
    it.mustRunAfter(tasks.named('compileGsonViews'))
}
```

However, that sis not help the performance :(

Comment: If you are using `5.1.0` for `grailsGradlePluginVersion`, try `5.1.1`.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown I am on 5.1.1

Comment: "I am on 5.1.1" - I am aware of the problem happening when using `grailsGradlePluginVersion` version 5.1.0 which is configured by default in Grails 5.1.1 apps.  I thought updating `grailsGradlePluginVersion` to 5.1.1 would make the problem go away.  I am not sure what is going wrong in your project if that doesn't fix it but if you can share a sample app, I would be happy to look at it.

Comment: Added steps to reproduce on the original post.

Comment: I am not sure what is going wrong with that.  I am sorry that I cannot help.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, upgrading to grails 5.1.2 results in the error still logging out but no longer causes it to actually fail

Comment: It was never causing a failure, just performance issues. I managed to get the error go away (see the answer below), but the slowness is still there :)